# How does complex webbrowser games like Battlefield Heroes work?

Tags: java, flash, activex

I am curious about how battlefield heroes works - it is a game playable in your web browser, and it is quite alot more complex than your average webbrowser game. Does anyone know what technology it is based on? Flash, ActiveX, Applets....?

EDIT: What technology does Age Of Empires Online use?

Comment: Battlefield Heroes was not developed with this, but check http://unity3d.com/.

Comment: Battlefield Heroes is not playable in your browser itself. It executes a program on your computer which is the game.

Comment: I see. What about Age Of Empires Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is just used for the frontend. They aren't going to throw away the code they used on their Battlefield series of games, and code something entirely different for this. The actual game will use some native tunnelling like ActiveX or other browser plugins.

Comment: I see. What about Age Of Empires Online?

Comment: It looks like C++, I don't think you play it from the website? Again, they aren't likely to throw away the code they used for the previous games in their series. The game looks decent, too.

Answer (score 0):

Flash seems to be used on that website.

Answer (score 0):

The easy (but not fool-proof) way to check is to simply right-click on the game. If it was done using Flash then the Flash menu will pop up.